# How to hide TimePicker and DatePicker on lifecycle events in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm running into an issue on android where our TimePicker and DatePicker stay visible when we navigate OnPause(). We need to redirect our users back to the login screen when they background the application, but if the TimePicker or DatePicker is active when they do this it stays on the screen. It appears above the login screen and pressing cancel or ok crashes the app.

We are hooking into the native android lifecycle events (not just using Xamarins built in hooks) and we redirect OnResume(). I've tested this in a barebones app though and it still happens OnPause().

Here is our TimePicker causing us the issue:

```
<TimePicker x:Name="VitalTimePicker" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" IsVisible="false" PropertyChanged="OnTimePickerPropertyChanged"/>
```

And here is an example of changing screens on a lifecycle event:

```
protected override void OnSleep()
    {
        App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new NotesPage());
    }
```

Any ideas? I was thinking of clearing the Pickers but I can't seem to find how to do that

**Edit**

Just to add a little more context

The [Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/application-class) class (app.xaml.cs) has [lifecycle hooks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/app-lifecycle) that we use to catch when our users background the app. In here we call `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new LoginPage());` which takes the app back to the login page.

I've added

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()  
   {
       VitalTimePicker.Unfocus();
       VitalDatePicker.Unfocus();
   }
```

to the view i'm working from and it seems to be called when we background the application, but for some reason the TimePicker is staying on the screen when our login page pops up again.

Comment: Could you please share a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Answer (score 0):

You can programmatically close `DatePickers` and `TimePickers` using the method `Unfocus()`. I'd recommend closing them **before** you call the next page, as I don't know if they will be able to be referenced and closed after the other screen has been initialized.

Create a method that calls `VitalTimePicker.Unfocus()` and the same for any other picker you have, and call this method before changing to login screen and you should be good to go.

Comment: Perfect answer, I am still having an issue though because I'm using `OnDisappear()` to unfocus the pickers but I think on android it isn't called since we're adding our login screen to the top of the stack. Any other way you could think of calling this?

Comment: @Beartooth426 Can't you unfocus the pickers right before you call the method to add the login screen to the stack?

Comment: I'm not sure I could pass a reference to the control to the app class that controls lifecycle events

Comment: @Beartooth426 There should be a place in your code where you're calling an Intent, or Xamarin navigation, that opens the login page. Don't use any lifecycle event, you can just unfocus the pickers right before you're calling the page that's causing the problem. Post some code of where you're calling the login page if you still have problems so I can help you out a little better.